# Android Studio encoding item of listview

Tags: android, listview, encoding

I have a problem with ListView item using android studio.

```
this.setTitle("é ç è ");

ArrayList<String> Array = new ArrayList<String>();
Array.add("é ç   è");
Array.add("à de");
Array.add("chére");
List = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.LV_List );
LV_List.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,Array));
```

It can't be encoded for items of ListView !!!!

looking to screeshot
http://hpics.li/48fe3c0

Info: 
- Using the same code, I'had not this problem in Eclipse
- My Android Studio Version: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/818235Capture.png

Answer (score 0):

Try to adding this in build.gradle

```
tasks.withType(Compile) {
options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
```